# Angular 7 and html2Canvas iterating an array using foreach always download the last found index

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0, html2canvas, angular7

I am iterating over an array in typescript to take a snapshot of a div having id equal to the index of the array and download an image file.

If the array was having 2 rows, 2 images should be downloaded. Here is the script:

```
public toCanvas() {
    let i = Object.keys(this.array).length;

    Object.keys(this.array).forEach((key, index)=>{
               var elem = document.getElementById(index.toString());

console.log(index)
      html2canvas(elem).then(function(canvas) {
        var generatedImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        window.location.href=generatedImage;
      });


    })
  }
```

Using `Object.keys(this.array).forEach((key, index)`, I am iterating to get the index, and then find the document `getElementId(index)`.

The problem is that it always download the last image.

And at the console, the indexes are consoled, at the beginning and then the image is downloaded:

[image]

The html script:

```
<mat-card [id]="i"  *ngFor="let arrayOfData of array; let i=index; "  class="example-card"  #matCard>
```

I tried using `while` inside `forEach()`:

```
public toCanvas() {
    let i = Object.keys(this.array).length;
    Object.keys(this.array).forEach((key, index) => {
      while (i != -1) {
        i--;
        console.log(i)
        var elem = document.getElementById(index.toString());


        html2canvas(elem).then(function (canvas) {
          var generatedImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
          window.location.href = generatedImage;
        });
      }

    })
  }
```

And it's doing the same behavior. It consoles the index until it reaches to `0` and then downloads the image of the last detected `<mat-card>`

**EDIT**

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/download-div-using-canvas-rjoxqx) of the recursive method provided by @xyz.

Comment: I think just replacing `var` with `let` will solve your problem, but I don't think this is how you should do it. Never run async calls in a loop.

Comment: @xyz okay. Can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: @xyz I mean about async calls

Comment: @xyz it didn't work with `var`

Comment: Lil busy, I will add an answer in a while if it hasn't already been answered and what did you replace? Replace `var elem = docum..` with `let elem = doc...`. It has it work. `let` gives block scope to variables so every loop is a new block while `var` gives a function scope so the same element the rewritten and the last value is used to download your image. Also replace `var generatedImage` with `let generatedImage`

Comment: @xyz I tried changing all `var` to `let` but still the same issue. I will wait for your answer. I guess, no one will answer this question.

Comment: @xyz you still buzzy man ? I really need your help.

Comment: On it! Please show how your `array` looks like, I see you are looping twice. I will frame an answer with a normal array for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation may be different, change the code accordingly. Considering the elements in the array is like: `array = [0, 1, 2];`. And elements in the array are the ids of divs that you want to download. So your divs are like:

```
<div [id]="id" *ngFor="let id of array">
  I am div id: {{id}}
</div>
```

**Implementation 1**
You can leverage `rxjs` to download the divs in a sequence, lets make the array as an Observable and work on each value in the array before starting the next download(Will use `concatMap` for this).

```
  public downloadDivs() {
    from(this.array).pipe(
      concatMap((arrayElem) => {
        let docElem = document.getElementById(arrayElem.toString());
        return from(html2canvas(docElem).then(function (canvas) {
          let generatedImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
          let a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = generatedImage;
          a.download = `${arrayElem}.png`;
          a.click();
          return `${arrayElem}.png`;
        }));
      })
    ).subscribe((imageName) => {
      console.log("Image downloaded", imageName);
    }) 
  }
```

Your HTML has this button to trigger the call:

```
<button (click)="downloadDivs()">Download divs using rxjs</button>
```

**Implementation 2**
call the download of the next `div` only after the download of one div is complete. I have used `recursion` for this.

```
public trivialDownload() {
  console.log("Downloading image one by one, without a loop");
  this._download(0, this.array);
}

// this method will keep calling itself until all the elements of the array are scanned
private _download(index, array) {
  if (index >= array.length) {
    console.log("Done!")
  } else {
    let docElem = document.getElementById(array[index].toString());
      html2canvas(docElem).then((canvas) => {
        let generatedImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = generatedImage;
        a.download = `${array[index]}.png`;
        a.click();
        // at this point, image has been downloaded, then call the next download.
        this._download(index + 1, array)
      });
  }
}
```

See this link for the implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/download-div-using-canvas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Error saying: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
    at html2canvas` I think it is pointing to `docElem` from the first implementation

Comment: And if I console `this.array` I will get `[Object Object]` instead of the real value

Comment: The array contain 5 fields: `id`, `name`, `name_other`, `gender`, and `dob`.

Comment: The second implementation is not working as well as it is not reading `array[index].toString()`

Comment: @alim1990: Please show the contents of your array, of course it will not work if it is not a simple array as given in the example, also refer the stackblitz link added in the answer

Comment: Okay let me show you the full array as I didn't make the stackblitz: https://imgur.com/a/XX6TgNB

Comment: @alim1990: Sorry for the late replies, now show the HTML what ids they contain.(the one which you are trying to download) You can update your question itself with all relevant details.

Comment: `<div   *ngFor="let arrayOfData of array; let i=index; ">
<mat-card  id="{{i}}" class="example-card"  #matCard>`

Comment: Okay, check the previous comment, while I am working on a stackblitz.

Comment: @alim1990: Yeah, stackblitz would be the best. From your comments, if you do `from(Object.keys(this.array)).pipe......` in the first implementation in the answer, your code should work

Comment: Oh it worked. But I prefer the recursive method as it does not need the Rx library

Comment: Okay, great! Implementation depends on you.

Comment: Is it good to use RxJS in a project ? This is the first component, whereas I use it in the whole project and I am afraid that it is going to increase the bundle size (I am using lazy loading).

Comment: @alim1990 If you are making an angular project, then `rxjs` will help you a lot!! There are so many thing which promises can't do, one way or another you will turn to using `rxjs`. Using `rxjs` in this example may be unnecessary if we can do it with a simple logic then ofcourse we can avoid it.

Comment: I know. That's why I am trying to use the simple logic method. I will get back to you with stackblitz

Comment: Here is the stackblitz with the exact array of mine using the recursive method. please check it https://stackblitz.com/edit/download-div-using-canvas-rjoxqx

Comment: @alim1990 see this working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/download-div-using-canvas-5c53ha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.